# can make more than 2 dimensional Matrix using math.net

Tags: c#, math.net

I need to use a 4 dimensional matrix.

I am using [math.net numeric](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) library for c#,

I have tried the

```
Matrix<Matrix<double>> test;
```

but it didn't work

i know that I can write the following

```
Matrix<double> [][] test;
```

but I don't want it this way

Comment: I'd suggest looking into a math.net's tensor as a multidimensional array(or > 2d matrix). Math.Net says it supports them. How did that not work? If it compiled, then ship it.

Answer (score 3):

No. The Math.NET Numerics Linear Algebra functionality operates on vectors and matrices, not on arbitrary-dimensional arrays (by design; other than libraries like ILNumerics which do operate on such arrays). As such it does not provide a 4 dimensional "matrix"-like data structure.

Do you really need tensor-arithmetics on top of that, or is this more about storing a table of matrices (or a cube of vectors)?

Comment: Yes I need tensor-arithmetics on the top of it
I Think I will use the (Matrix<double> [][] test;) way :(